# How can I group and intersect the results from two selects on a particular column, and then return all matching rows from both?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, intersection

I have a mysql table with results from many different sources, basically with columns:

```
id     (PRIMARY KEY)
source (INT)
value  (VARCHAR)
score  (FLOAT)
```

Example

```
id source value score
-- ------ ----- -----
1    1     dog   0.2
2    1     cat   2.5
3    1     pig   4.0
4    2     dog   2.3
5    2     dog   1.5
6    2     cat   1.4
7    2     hen   0.7
```

I need to perform set operations on *sources*, e.g. `1 ∩ 2 ∩ 3` or `(1 + 2 + 3) ∩ (4 + 5 + 6)` (where + means union), but using the *value* as the key, and returning full rows. I'm converting expressions to select statements (each nested subexpression becomes a select). These are requests over the web, so performance is a concern, but on the other hand I will cache the results after the initial request.

Let's see how I can query for rows in an intersection of two sources based on the value, using `1 ∩ 2` as an example. I can get the *values* with

```
SELECT value
FROM table
WHERE source=1 OR source=2
GROUP BY value HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT source) = 2
```

And, I can even get the rows back with

```
SELECT table.id, table.value, table.source
FROM (
    SELECT value
    FROM table
    WHERE source=1 OR source=2
    GROUP BY value HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT source) = 2) AS intersection
JOIN table ON intersection.value = table.value
WHERE table.source=1 or table.source=2
```

yielding

```
id source value score
-- ------ ----- -----
1    1     dog   0.2
2    1     cat   2.5
4    2     dog   2.3
5    2     dog   1.5
6    2     cat   1.4
```

However, it isn't a readily usable solution for the nested expressions I need to handle because it goes back to the original table and restricts based on source again. Consider instead finding the intersection of the results of two selects, where each select statement produces a subset of the data table. I can no longer join to the full table. I would have to join the intersection with the union of the two selects, but that just doesn't seem scalable at all.

A different way I thought was to use GROUP_CONCAT on the ids, and then split the list of ids back out to rows (either in a [stored procedure](http://www.marcogoncalves.com/2011/03/mysql-split-column-string-into-rows/) or in python). That stored procedure made me think that instead maybe I should just write my own procedure for the whole query.

So, is there another way to do these queries with vanilla sql? If not, I will try writing a stored procedure (never done it before, should be fun). Is a stored procedure the best way to go here, and any recommendation on using the first solution (temp tables and joins), the second solution (group_concat and split), or a third solution entirely? I don't know enough about stored procedures to know how fine grained I can get.

Comment: Can you provide a table that shows the output you are trying to generate?  It is a bit hard to follow set notation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What do you mean? I already included the output.

Comment: Your text gives the data, two examples of queries (that you don't like), and then a table of results. It isn't clear if the results are the right answer, or the answer from queries that you don't like. I see now that you intend for these to be correct. I just found the phrasing ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this statement "Specifically, how can I query for rows in an intersection of two sources based on the value?", it seems that you want to specify one or more sources and return all rows that have matching values.

```
select *
from t
where t.source in (select 1 as source union all select 2 as source) and
      t.value in (select value
                  from (select 1 as source union all select 2 as source) sources join
                       t
                       on t.source = sources.source
                  group by value
                  having count(distinct t.source) = 2
                 )
```

In this version, you have to put in the list of sources twice (once in the subquery and once in the outer query) and hardcode the number "2".  In other databases, this would be easy using the "with" clause to define the list as an alias that could be re-used throughout the query, but mysql does not support that.

If you placed the source list in a table called s, then you could use:

```
select *
from t
where t.source in (select source from s) and
      t.value in (select value
                  from s join
                       t
                       on t.source = s.source cross join
                       (select count(*) as cnt from s) const
                  group by value
                  having count(distinct t.source) = max(const.cnt)
                 )
```

Comment: For starters, why `(SELECT 1 AS source UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS source) AS sources JOIN t ON t.source=sources.source` instead of just `WHERE t.source=1 or t.source=2`? Other than that, this is identical to what I suggested. I don't really think it works when I'm doing something like `((1+2)-(3+4)) ∩ (5+6)`

Comment: @jmilloy . . . because one way to solve your problem is to put the sources into a table, and then derive the rest of the information in the query.  You can't do that in a WHERE statement.  You can do that by putting the data into a table.

Comment: Okay. That's not relevant to my question because I don't have a list of sources, I have an expression with set-like operations on sources. The part you've redone I can already do (the sql I show does the same thing as yours), and in fact your solution is even harder to generalize. Can you see that in some cases, I need to intersect two subsets of rows, where the subset is the result of a previous operation?

Comment: Ah, I see. I've edited the question slightly to make it clearer.